# Shouldn't there be a "I'm done" button?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was in the review section when I got up to a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4623433). It had some content that I thought was commentary, the part where he said

> I temporarily give up here. If you fix these issues and edit your question I'll help further.

This means, that he needs further clarification of the question and is not yet posting the answer that would help the community.

So, I just posted a comment saying that this is a commentary post and blah blah you can read that there. So what I expected it to do was, to change the buttons and show me a I'm Done button. But instead it kept showing me **Looks Good** and Recommend Deletion buttons.

This is the screenshot for the event:

[image]

What would have you did in such a case when you've had played the part you had to play and now you want to continue to the next post. Since the looks good button would trigger this-post-is-safe and the recommend deletion would be a flag for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's Not An Answer.  It should be deleted.  You should be recommending deletion on such a post.

This will automatically add an appropriate comment and push the post towards deletion.

Answer (score 4):

You have all three buttons you need.

- Looks good: You think the post is acceptable.
- Recommend deletion: You think the post is unacceptable.
- Skip: You are not sure if it's acceptable or not, and want to let others weigh in.

Editing or commenting doesn't change that in any way.  You're still free to 'skip' if you aren't sure if even post-edit or post-comment whether it should be kept or deleted.